# Elasticsearch autocomplete searching middle word

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm stuck on this for a while.

How can I get suggestion on elastic search to complete my word even when I write a middle term.
For example in my data I have "Alan Turing is great" and I start typing "turi", I would like to see suggestion term "Alan Turing is Great".

I am using elastic search v. 6.3.2, I tried with query similar to these:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"_source":false,"suggest":{"show-suggest":{"prefix":"turi","completion":{"field":"auto_suggest"}}}}'
```

or

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"_source":false,"suggest":{"show-suggest":{"text":"turi","completion":{"field":"auto_suggest"}}}}'
```

but it works only if I search for "alan" and it shows all the terms.

index:

```
"tokenizer": {
    "my_tokenizer": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 3,
      "max_gram": 4,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit"
      ]
    }
  }
}



"mappings": {
"poielement": {
  "numeric_detection": false,
  "date_detection": false,
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "suggestions": {
        "match": "suggest_*",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "copy_to": "auto_suggest",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "property": {
        "match": "*",
        "mapping": {
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "auto_suggest": {
      "type": "completion"
    },
    "name_suggest": {
      "type": "completion"
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Try **match phrase** query. Also if you can share mapping of index people may suggest better approach.

Comment: i added the index, I had to cut some parts cos stackoverflow doesn't allow me to insert much code

Comment: @AntonioMele , I have handled this use case, writing my answer, please comment if you don't understand anything.

Comment: @NishantSaini I have tried with it but I got the same result. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

We have an exact similar use case and this is how we solved it. what you are looking is for `substring` search.

Please create a `custom substring` analyzer for your field like below, java code for which is below:-

```
        TokenStream result = new WhitespaceTokenizer(SearchManager.LUCENE_VERSION_301, reader);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(SearchManager.LUCENE_VERSION_301, result);
        result = new SubstringFilter(result, minSize);
        return result;
```

In the above code, I am first using the `WhitespaceTokenizer` and then passing it to first `LowerCaseFilter` and then my **custom** `SubstringFilter` code of which is customizable based on the minimum no of chars you want in your tokens.

Above code will generate below tokens for strings like `hellowworld` if you set min substring length 3.

Giving public URI to access the tokens which it generates as for `helloworld` string and min substring length 3. it will generate lot of tokens.

https://justpaste.it/4i6gh

Also you can test the tokens which your custom analyzer using the `_analyze` api, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

http://localhost:9200/jaipur/_analyze?text=helloworld&analyzer=substring

here jaipur is my index name and `helloworld` is the string for which I want to generates tokens using `substring`.

**EDIT**
As suggested by Nishant in comments, you can use the ngram filter instead of substring filter, which Elastic inbuilt provides.

Comment: You could have done the substring part using ngram token filter.

Comment: I am not sure about what you suggested me, but I already defined ngram tokenizer on my analyzer. But I am new to es so I may have not done it properly

Comment: @AntonioMele , can you provides the tokens which your analyzer created ?